# Javascript Seconds to HMS not working with float points

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to convert seconds to Hour seconds and minutes, i have a function to do this which is working fine for Numbers, when we call the same function with floating points which i consider as milliseconds it all ways returning "0.00"

```
function secondsToHms(d) {
    d = Number(d);
    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);
    return ((h > 0 ? h + ":" + (m < 10 ? "0" : "") : "") + m + ":" + (s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s);
}
```

Fiddle : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ghc37sa3/)

i don't know why the floating points are not working with this function

Comment: 0.345 sec isn't supposed to return 0 secs ?

Comment: milliseconds are less than 1 second, so a floor will return 0.

Comment: How to make it  work with milliseconds ?

Comment: It's working fine. `0.345` is `0` seconds, `0.999999` is `0` seconds. `1.001` is `1` second and so on

Comment: Unless you want to display milliseconds at the end of your HMS format, you can't. floor(0.999) will always return 0